# Is there a convenient way to compare a value of an element with its predecessor in a SwiftUI ForEach-View?

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui

I am looking for a solution to compare two values in an ForEach-View in SwiftUI

```
    @ObservedObject var myInstance : SomeInstance = SomeInstance()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(myInstance.someObjects) { someObject in
// if (someObject.someValue == someObject.prevSibling().someValue) (...)
        }
}
```

In a common for-loop you could access the element by using the current index minus 1. Am I missing something or do I think to control-struct-centric to solve this one?

Comment: Search usually helps... Just answered in previous tag post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63379366/12299030

Comment: And what happens with the first element (that has no previous)? In any case, I always find it to be better to make the view model easy to work with before it get used by the view

Comment: @Asperi: Thanks for the shared post! I indeed searched for the topic in multiple ways, but I guess I did not find the answer as it was posted while I was writing this one :). I'll check this out as soon as possible.

Comment: @NewDev: I fully agree with your concerns with this pseudo-code sibling access and the fact that this should not be handled at rendering time at all, this is indeed way too hacky. But i was really curious if this requirement could be met in the given example.